# Org-cycle with TAB from isearch without RET

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, isearch

When I've  `isearch`ed for something in a headline in org-mode, and my cursor is sitting on the headline I want: how do I `org-cycle` that headline with <kbd>TAB</kbd>? Currently I have to first press <kbd>RET</kbd> then <kbd>TAB</kbd>. I would like to save the <kbd>RET</kbd> keystroke if possible. Looking for the Emacs Lisp for configuration.

Comment: `C-s` is modal: you get into a state where you can use a limited number of keys and stay within that mode (e.g. `C-s` to go the the next match, `C-r` to go backwards) - do `C-h f isearch-forward` and check the `isearch-mode-map` section to see what those keys are. While in that mode, however, any *other* keys get added to the search string: you need to *exit* that mode for keys to be normally interpreted and that's what `RET` does. IOW, there is no way to do what you want with `isearch`: it makes iterative, interactive searching easier but the modal nature of it requires a way to exit from it.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `TAB` to exit Isearch and do its regular (non-Isearch) thing, then just bind it in `isearch-mode-map` to `isearch-exit` (the same function `RET` is bound to):

```lisp
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'isearch-exit)
```

I don't recommend that, however, as you might want to search for a TAB character by hitting the `TAB` key...

Comment: Was not aware of isearch-mode-map and isearch-exit synergy. This is great. I have solved my problem with this. Thank you very much. Regarding your anti-recommendation, I'm not worried. Can bind C-M-TAB to insert TAB into search string if I ever encounter this issue. I've been using Emacs a while and have literally never searched for a TAB character.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `isearch`, you should be using `org-occur`.   See

```lisp
(info "(org) Sparse Trees")
```

or

[Sparse Trees (The Org Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Sparse-Trees.html)

---

`org-occur` (`C-c / r` or `C-c / /`)

Prompts for a regexp (see [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Regular-Expressions.html)) and shows a sparse tree with all matches.

- If the match is in a headline, the headline is made visible.
- If the match is in the body of an entry, headline and body are made visible.

In order to provide minimal context, also the full hierarchy of headlines above the match is shown, as well as the headline following the match.

Each match is also highlighted; the highlights disappear when the buffer is changed by an editing command, or by pressing `C-c C-c` .

When called with a `C-u` prefix argument, previous highlights are kept, so several calls to this command can be stacked.

Comment: Sparse trees are great, but this answer does not address the specific question that I was asking.